# OSTicket users reply using the email not added to the ticket thread

Tags: php, osticket

I have a problem with OSTicket:

**The problem:** When the users create a ticket every thing is working fine except **If the replied by their emails the replies not added to the ticket thread** also we can't know that the replied.

Can you please help us in this problem?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569). In summary, asking us to hurry up makes it even _less likely_ that you get a (good) answer.

Comment: Thanks I edited my question but I was working on if for more days and our website is Live and we get a lot of tickets every day and I can't solve it

Comment: That question is likely to be [off-topic for Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) anyway. Maybe better have a look at [OSTicket's support site](http://osticket.com/support), or try https://serverfault.com/

Comment: Dear Adrian, More questions added here and they were OSticket issues So please If you can help me add you reply If You can't let other people may help me Thanks for your time and reply

Comment: Does the new email end up as new ticket? Is there a problem mentioned in admin panel dashboard?

Comment: Thanks a lot Miroslav for your reply!, Emails are working fine when ticket created ,both agent and user receive notification but when the user reply from his email this reply is not added to the ticket thread!